# Возникла проблема с версткой макета с использованием bootstrap 3

Tags: bootstrap

Возникла проблема с версткой макета с использованием Bootstrap 3.

HTML:

```
<div class="row header-main">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="header-logo" src="images/enjoy-logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="header-phone col-lg-6">
                <span>(</span>066<span>)</span>161-28-01
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="header-btn col-lg-6"><a href="#">Обратный звонок</a></button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input class="header-search" type="text" placeholder="Поиск..." />
                <img class="header-search_icon" src="images/header-search_icon.png" width="16" height="16" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
            <ul class="header-social">
                <li><a class="sprite-skype_icon" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="sprite-vk_icon" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="sprite-twitter_icon" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="sprite-googleplus_icon" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="sprite-facebook_icon" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="sprite-youtube_icon" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="header-basket">
            <a class="header-basket_link" href="#">Корзина:<br /><span>0 грн</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Необходимо задать один фон для всех колонок, добавляю фон через класс `header-main`, но тогда фон заполняет всю ширину `row`. Как мне задать фон именно для колонок не затрагивая отступы `row` элемента?